# dice game with square around it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey everyone i'm trying to make a dice square as a beginner that went pretty much fine until I tried to create a square around the number that would be returned ,

```
import random

def roll():

    letter = ''
    while not (letter == 'YES'):
      print('Do you want to to roll?')
      letter = input().upper()

      if letter == 'YES':
        x = random.randint(1,6)
        square()
      elif letter != 'YES':
        return("dommage")
    inputPlayerLetter()

def square(x):
 x = random.randint(1,6)
 print (' _____')
 print ('|     |')
 print ('|', x , '|')
 print ('|_____|')
```

I'm pretty much stuck at this point and don't really now what to change or add , if someone has an idea it would be really nice.

Comment: What is the problem with your code that you want to fix?

Comment: @khelwood I want to have a square around the digit (1,6) that comes out like the front of a dice

Comment: As @khelwood said what are the problem you want to address, because there's a bunch. Also, make sure to include all the relevant code (Aka. `inputPlayerLetter()`).

Comment: @Basho No, that's what your trying to do. What is the problem with your code that you need to fix? Does it produce an error? Does it produce the wrong output?

Comment: You have this comment: `# the first element in the tuple is the player's letter, the second is the computer's letter.` But I can't see any tuples in that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `square` function expects a parameter `x`, and yet in `roll` you call `square()` without an argument. You should pass `x` to it, and remove the redundant `x = random.randint(1,6)` from the `square` function.

Comment: Thanks ! i have some troubles to understand when and what to put in the functions parameter !

Answer (score 1):

Your square function is missing the parameter `x`.

```
import random

def roll():

    letter = ''
    while not (letter == 'YES'):
        print('Do you want to to roll?')
        letter = input().upper()

    # the first element in the tuple is the player's letter, the second is the computer's letter.
    if letter == 'YES':
        x = random.randint(1,6)
        square(x)
    elif letter != 'YES':
        return("dommage")
    inputPlayerLetter()

def square(x):
    x = random.randint(1,6)
    print (' _____')
    print ('|     |')
    print ('|', x , '|')
    print ('|_____|')
```

prints me the following output

```
Do you want to to roll?
yes
 _____
|     |
| 4 |
|_____|

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-26b32eade6f0> in <module>()
----> 1 roll()

<ipython-input-57-5376e02fea33> in roll()
     14     elif letter != 'YES':
     15         return("dommage")
---> 16     inputPlayerLetter()
     17 
     18 def square(x):

NameError: name 'inputPlayerLetter' is not defined
```

make sure to have the function `inputPlayerLetter` already defined

Comment: yes my bad i forgot to change the name whne posting inputPlayer is indeed roll()

Answer (score 0):

I reorganised your code a little. If the player inputs `no`, or any word starting with `n` or `N`, the game stops, otherwise it prints a new number. We just use a simple `while` loop to do the looping. That's better than having the `roll` function call itself. I also fixed a spacing error in the `square` function.

```
import random

def square(x):
    print(' _____')
    print('|     |')
    print('| ', x, ' |')
    print('|_____|')

def roll():
    while True:
        letter = input('Do you want to roll? [Y/n] ').lower()
        if letter.startswith('n'):
            print("Dommage")
            break
        else:
            square(random.randint(1, 6))

roll()
```

**typical output**

```
Do you want to roll? [Y/n] Yes
 _____
|     |
|  5  |
|_____|
Do you want to roll? [Y/n] y
 _____
|     |
|  6  |
|_____|
Do you want to roll? [Y/n] maybe
 _____
|     |
|  4  |
|_____|
Do you want to roll? [Y/n] no
Dommage
```